# How to undo quick formatted linux partition from windows?

Tags: partition-recovery

I accidentally formatted my Linux(centos) root partition from windows.

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve the partition with [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).

Testdisk is a console tool to recover missing partitions and files. It depends how much the disk has been overwritten, but I had good results regardless.

**How to**

[Taken from here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

1. Start the program.
2. Select the Create Log option.
3. Select the disk that had the partition in the next screen. If You have more than one disk, this might be hard if You don't recognize the disks. Otherwise there will be only one option.
4. Select the partition table (Intel/PC for MBR).
5. Select analyze and Quick Search. Wait for the program to complete.
6. If the partition is not found or the partition doesn't correspond with the expected size, then You can try a deep scan, which could take hours to complete depending on the disk size.
7. If the partition was found, then select the Write option.